# codeigniter load multiple applications

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-applications, architecture

What I want to do is to have a `base application` folder which is shared among all `Code Igniter` websites. This application folder provides some functions and cores which will be shared with many other applications. Both `base` application and `extended` application should be loaded at the same time. Is it possible with `CI`?

for example: if have a website with two subdomains which have different applications but they have a base application in common

```
/www/common/application_base
```

as following:

mywebsite.com

```
/www/mywebsite/application_extended
/www/common/application_base
```

subdomain1.mywebsite.com

```
/www/sub1_mywebsite/application_extended
/www/common/application_base
```

subdomain2.mywebsite.com

```
/www/sub2_mywebsite/application_extended
/www/common/application_base
```

Comment: @Jakub, you can have separate apps and use one of them only at the same time. but i need to share controllers and models of both together.

Comment: You still don't understand when I say domain routing, read this: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/89424/

Comment: using routing does not disable some controllers.